# Как декодировать JSON?

Tags: json, php, кодировка

1. Есть запись вида "Ð'Ð'Ð Ð \"Ð\" Ð  Ð Ð" и её нужно как-то декодировать.
2. После json_decode выдаёт null, после json_encode выдаёт "\u00d0'\u00d0'\u00d0 \u00d0".

Comment: а какой злодей вам сказал что это JSON ?

Comment: Ну так я запись получаю из json...

Comment: ну это в принципе похоже на JSON по крайней мере для javascript :) (строка просто) вот и ideone со мной согласен

http://ideone.com/TC059D

убедитесь что двойные кавычки есть по сторонам строки.

Comment: Это все-таки JSON, или это то, что получено из JSON?

Comment: @Fike я думаю это JSON.stringify из js скорее всего у ТС слетела кодировка по дороге.

@aspermags убедитесь, что у вас везде стоит UTF8

Comment: Я не могу убедиться - я получаю данные с сервера, который принадлежит Мариссе Майер...

Comment: скорее всего Марисса передает utf8 а у вас кодировка не правильная.

Comment: Откуда данные получили?

Эти крякозябы похожи на такие ("Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð¹ÑÐºÐ¾Ðµ") декодер лебедева выдает ISO-8859-1 → UTF-8. Попробуйте засунуть в [него][1] более длинные куски текста.


  [1]: http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/